# How to makes all of child view remain untransparent while its parent view transparent when designing background in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-view

I was intended to makes a parent view which contains a background from my own gradient-handmade-background transparent and it was successfully applied into my **MainActivity.xml** file. But when i was trying to put a button inside that parent view, those buttons accidentally become transparent too. How do i makes my button untransparent while my parent view remain transparent?

Here is my code for my MainActivity.xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/bgutama">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </Button>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my code for **bgutama.xml**, a gradient-handmade-background which contains gradiented two color used for my background for **MainActivity.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
         android:startColor="#ff0000"
         android:endColor="#0004ff"
         android:angle="0"/>
      <stroke
         android:width="2dip"
         android:color="#ff000000"/>
      <corners
        android:radius="5dip"/>
      <padding
        android:left="15dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:top="10dip"
        android:bottom="10dip"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set alpha for your FrameLayout. Instead, modify the gradients' colors. For example:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#90ff0000"
    android:endColor="#900004ff"
    android:angle="0"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#90000000"/>
```

Notice the '90' I added to the beginning of each color: that's the alpha. Just set this value to whatever transparency you need